# Getting [object] as a button value in Sahi

Tags: javascript, sahi

I am working on Sahi and got stuck with this issue.

**Issue:** I am getting [object] as a value instead of value "true" while asserting the button attribute.

**Code:**
File 1: category.sah

```
_include("newCatLib.sah");
_click($tabCategory);
_assertEqual("Category Details", _getText($heading), "");
disabledBtn($lowLvlCatEdtBtn, true, $subLvlCatEdtBtn, true);
```

File 2: newCatLib.sah

```
var $tabCategory = _span("title[2]"); 
var $heading = _heading3("page-title");
var $highLvlCatDrpdn = _select(0);
var $lowLvlCatDrpdn = _select(1);
var $subLvlCatDrpdn = _select(2);
var $lowLvlCatEdtBtn = _button(0);
var $subLvlCatEdtBtn = _button(1);

function disabledBtn($lowLvlCatEdtBtn, $boolean1, $subLvlCatEdtBtn, $boolean2) {
var $isDisabledBtn1 = _getAttribute($lowLvlCatEdtBtn, "disabled");
_assertEqual($boolean1, $isDisabledBtn1);
var $isDisabledBtn2 = _getAttribute($subLvlCatEdtBtn, "disabled");
_assertEqual($boolean2, $isDisabledBtn2);
}
```

**Execution Log:**

```
[-] **disabledBtn([object], true, [object], true)**
_assertEqual(true, true) [257 ms] [08:28:29.537]
_assertEqual(true, true) [253 ms] [08:28:29.790]
```

I have checked Button accessor in HTML code which is correct.

Comment: the function call looks legit and _getAttribute($subLvlCatEdtBtn, "disabled") evaluates to true. So what's wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Please, refactor your code and leave everything out which is not relevant for the question, that makes your question easier to understand and will most likely answer it

```
var $btn1 = _button(0);
var $btn2 = _button(1);
disabledBtn($btn1);
disabledBtn($btn2);

function disabledBtn($btn) {
  var $isDisabled = _getAttribute($btn, "disabled");
  _assertTrue($isDisabled);
}
```